# Default.aspx being served when debugging locally

Tags: asp.net, webserver

Any ideas why the built in asp.net webserver insists on serving "/default.aspx" whenever you browse to the root "/"?

Even if you force the global.asax to redirect to "/" whenever "/default.aspx" is detected it will see "/" as a request to "/default.aspx" and an infinite loop ensues!

Anyone have a way around this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're talking about Cassini (the one Visual Studio comes with for development) - if so then you're out of luck because you can't change the default document it uses (or not in any way I know of anyway).

To work around it you can set your project to use a local IIS installation instead - that will give you more control over directory browsing, default documents etc.

Comment: Yea, i thought that was the case! iis is an option but i'm thinking of putting code in place to handle that 'special case'

Comment: @Adam - I'd say setting up IIS would be better as it would emulate the production environment better and the code to handle the 'special case' is only need during develpment.

Comment: I'd definately just go for IIS - you can setup a virtual directory to point to your code, so there's no complicated deployment nonsense, and every dev machine should be able to have IIS on it.

Comment: Ok good advice. One question though. Are there any quirks that IIS development may introduce? Switching from cassini just to solve this problem only to open another can o worms may be a tall order...

Comment: @Adam - It shouldn't do, it's the way we used to work before Cassini turned up and I would imagine it's going to be deployed to IIS for production anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Web projects (with Visual studio 2005 SP1 or 2008) you can modify the starting page that displays *when you start debugging from visual studio*.
You can change this in the 'Web' tab of the projects property pages, in the 'Start action' section.

-Edoode